# Custom database name for persisting host sagas

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

Is it possible to use custom database name (not endpoint) for persisting nservicebus host sagas using ravenDb?

I use NServiceBus 3.3 and RavenDB 2.5. and initialize endpoind in such way:

```
public class RavenConfig : IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
          Configure.Instance.RavenPersistence("AllHostsRavenDB");
          Configure.Instance.RavenSagaPersister();
          Configure.Instance.RavenSubscriptionStorage();
          Configure.Instance.UseRavenTimeoutPersister();
    }
 }
```

My App.config contains:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="AllHostsRavenDB" 
     connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8080; DefaultDatabase=ABC;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working! I changed my custom intitialization from:

```
public class RavenConfig : IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
      Configure.Instance.RavenPersistence("AllHostsRavenDB");
      Configure.Instance.RavenSagaPersister();
      Configure.Instance.RavenSubscriptionStorage();
      Configure.Instance.UseRavenTimeoutPersister();
    }
}
```

to:

```
public class RavenConfig : IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Configure.Instance.RavenPersistence("AllHostsRavenDB");
        Configure.Instance.RavenSagaPersister();
        Configure.Instance.RavenSubscriptionStorage();
        Configure.Instance.UseRavenTimeoutPersister();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> To control the database name in code, instead of via the
>   configuration, use the Configure.RavenPersistence(string
>   connectionStringName, string databaseName) signature. This can be
>   useful in a multitenant scenario.

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/ravendb/#nservicebus-3-and-nservicebus-4-overriding-the-defaults

Would that solve your problem?

Comment: You should be able to use `Configure.RavenPersistence("AllHostsRavenDB", databaseName_has_to_be_guid)` I think, but when I try I keep getting exceptions from raven about not specifying valid guid (although I'm pretty sure it's valid :)). I'll investigate and update you.